# Why integrate from x to 1 and not 0 to 1 in this case?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

For the problem 4 p.98/142 of this [PDF](http://cst.uwaterloo.ca/316/Notes/316-notes.pdf), why is the inner integration from x to 1 and not 0 to 1:

[image: img]

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The problem on p.10/83 of this [PDF](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~psarkar/sds321/lecture19-new.pdf), has a different arrangement, and its integrations are thus different.  Just leaving it here for reference.

[image: img]

Comment: Because $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ if $y<x$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: For any fixed $x$ $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is a constant function on $[c,1]$ as a function of $y$, and $0$ outside. And $x$ is the outer variable here.

Comment: In that case, why is the outer integral not from 0 to y?

Comment: The values you put as the lower and upper ends of an integral have to be expressed in terms of things outside the integral, not by things inside. If you put $y$ at the upper end of the outer integral, you're making the whole thing dependent on some $y$ value that comes from somewhere outside the integral. What $y$ value would that be? In contrast, the $x$ on the lower end of the inner integral comes from the $x$ in the $dx,$ which is outside the inner integral.

Comment: @DavidK, thank you so much!  What is the name of the rule you just mentioned?

Comment: After you integrate the second argument $y$ out in the inner integral, you will obtain the marginal pdf of $X$ which is independent of $y$, and the support of $X$ is $[0, 1]$. To "visualize" geometrically: the joint support is a triangle bounded by $y \leq 1, x \geq 0, x \leq y$ on the $x-y$ plane. The inner integral will found the volume under the joint pdf from $y = x$ to $y = 1$ (which is the area of the rectangle with height $c$ and length $1 - x$) for each value of $x$. The value at each $x$ is recorded and form the marginal pdf. And you find the area under this curve.

Comment: @BGM, thank you so much!!!

Comment: The comment by BGM should also help explain $f_X(X)$ in the second example in the question. As for the "rule" why the outermost bounds must be expressed in terms of things defined outside the integral, it is a simple consequence of the definition of a definite integral, which says if you have an interval $[a,b]$ and a function $f(x)$ then you can have a definite integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx.$ As this is a definition, all the things in the "if" part (including whatever you need for $a$ and $b$) must already exist _before_ you can apply the definition.